# ERROR: Dependency "talloc" not found, tried pkgconfig; How to install talloc dependency on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, meson-build, 5g, talloc

I am trying to download Open5gs on my 20.04 Ubuntu Machine but keep getting this error: 'Dependency "talloc" not found',
when I run the script "meson build --prefix='/pwd'/install

I tried fixing the issue using sudo apt-get install python3-talloc-dev but the error is still thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install `libtalloc-dev`, which provides the pkgconfig file for talloc